# Youtube parameters not working with thickbox

Tags: html, youtube, thickbox

Have some youtube videos that I'm trying to show with thick box and for some reason I can't remove the title bar, controls, or related videos. I've tried several different things, currently my working code looks like this:

```
<a class="thickbox" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/########&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600" title="###### Beckwith">
<img src="http://www.########.org/campaign/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2013/11/#Beckwith.png"/>
</a>
```

I hashed some info for the sake of privacy. Parameters need to be inserted before &KeepThis or else thickbox won't work. The problem is whenever I insert parameters they either don't work or the video won't play. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with YouTube API.
Star this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5595) to get updates on it.

Latest update :
`The rollback has being scheduled and should begin soon, but I don't have an exact timeline to share for when it will be fully completed. It's likely to be on the order of hours.`

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same issues yesterday too, so I'll wait it out for a while since I won't be working the next few days and see what it's doing when I come back.